# Openfire Crashing with Java Error

Tags: java, linux, nginx, chat, openfire

I am running a openfire based chat system in my server, but do get lot crashes related to the openfire java environment, i already increased the java VM memory to the 512MB but still it crashes when the server load exceeds,

i dont have many users only 20,30 at one time with a very powerful 8 core cpu, with 32 GB memory

i am running openfire 3.71. I have to restart the whole server, since restarting the openfire doenst fix the problem at all.

error i get in java is

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.jivesoftware.admin.LoginLimitManager.getInstance(LoginLimitManager.java:48)
    at org.jivesoftware.openfire.admin.login_jsp._jspService(login_jsp.java:143)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:97)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:530)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1216)
    at com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.filter.PageFilter.doFilter(PageFilter.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1187)
    at org.jivesoftware.util.LocaleFilter.doFilter(LocaleFilter.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1187)
    at org.jivesoftware.util.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1187)
    at org.jivesoftware.admin.PluginFilter.doFilter(PluginFilter.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1187)
    at org.jivesoftware.admin.AuthCheckFilter.doFilter(AuthCheckFilter.java:164)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1187)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:425)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:494)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:933)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:362)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:867)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:245)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:334)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:559)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:1007)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:747)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:209)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:406)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:462)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:436)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jivesoftware.util.TaskEngine.scheduleAtFixedRate(TaskEngine.java:228)
    at org.jivesoftware.admin.LoginLimitManager.(LoginLimitManager.java:83)
    at org.jivesoftware.admin.LoginLimitManager.(LoginLimitManager.java:33)
    at org.jivesoftware.admin.LoginLimitManager$LoginLimitManagerContainer.(LoginLimitManager.java:39)
    ... 36 more
```

Answer (score 0):

This error does not seem to be directly related to memory shortage - usually memory errors in Java are [`OutOfMemoryError`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/OutOfMemoryError.html) errors or refer to limited space for the permanent generation and such.

[`NullPointerException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html) exceptions, on the other hand, are almost certainly programming errors in the executed code. Since in your case this seems to happen under load, I can take a few shots in the dark:

- There is some finite resource, such as a thread pool or an event queue, that is being exhausted and the code that uses it does not check for that condition.
- There is a race condition, where some part of the code hits uninitialized structures that are normally being initialized by another thread under lighter load.
- There is some time out that is being reached, returning `null` that is then not handled properly.

Please note that the amount of memory available to the VM *can* affect the timing of various operations, due to the effect of the garbage collector running more or less frequently. You can use a profiler, such as [VisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/), to tell whether your application is starved for memory or not.

Comment: what is the maximum memory i can give to the java VM ? because when i try to add more than 2GB it seems openfire crashes

Comment: Does the JVM start? If it does not with more than 2GB then you are probably using either a 32-bit OS or a 32-bit JVM and you need both to be 64-bit for a VM to take more than 2GB on most operating systems...

Comment: how do check JVM start or not ? what i do is i pass the -Xms32m -Xmx128m, to openfire its called more heap settings, but i dont know how to increase memory in java since i am new to java 

http://community.igniterealtime.org/docs/DOC-1033

Comment: @user1179459: what I am asking is whether the JVM crashes immediately when you pass e.g. `-Xmx2048m`...

Comment: dotn knw about the jvm, but openfire dont start, thats why i asked you hwo do i know what JVM does ?

Comment: @user1179459: how do you start the JVM? And which OS are you using?

Comment: operating system is centos6, how i start openfire is "service openfire start"